# Reference number brackets wrapping to next line in Word 2007's bibliography

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, bibliography

Anyone ever encounter this problem in Word 2007?

[image: Awful Bibliography Line Breaks]

Word's automatic bibliography is not making the reference numbers column wide enough, so it's wrapping the closing bracket onto the next line. Is there any way to fix this? I can't manually change the column width, Word won't let me.

I'm using the IEEE 2006 bibliography style with the default Word 2007 Style Set.

I could make the font size smaller, but I'd prefer not to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This appears to be a defect in the IEEE 2006 style when you have long URLs in a citation.

One of my citations has a long URL that is just about the same width as the page. It forced the citation column to be wider, and squished the reference number column.

I edited that citation's URL to have a space so that the URL could wrap. Now it doesn't squish the reference number column.

I did try editing the citation style XSL file (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\Bibliography\Style\IEEE2006OfficeOnline.xsl). I replaced `<xsl:value-of select="'1%'"/>` with `<xsl:value-of select="'5%'"/>`. However this did not help because of the above problem with the long URL.

Comment: "**edited that citation's URL to have a space**" I agree this is the best solution (and ideally put the space just after a slash). This works best because it doesn't reset when you change a citation or update fields (unlike resizing the column heading) and won't break when you send the document to someone else (unlike editing teh XSL file).

Comment: Putting in a space is the only solution that consistently worked for me. I used a Zero-width space (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space), so that when copying the URLs from Word into a browser the sites remain accessible (the zero-space char is automatically ignored, while a regular space is not).

Comment: Thank you Lennart for the tip! I'd been using regular spaces to break up long citation URLs, but ZWSP looks way better (plus it leaves us with a *working* URL).

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to change the XSL style as explained in M. Dudley's answer (which simply did not work for me), you can simply change the column width by hovering next to the citation number column, then dragging it to the right when you get the cursor:

[image]

Note that you really need to change this column, and not the margins at the top ruler—otherwise you'll shift the entire bibliography to the right.

Comment: Which version of Word are you using?

Comment: Office 2013. Changing the values in the XSL template simply did not have any effect for me. But maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: The original Q&A were regarding Word 2007. I'm not surprised that the fix does not work on new versions.

Comment: Well, I am surprised it doesn't work—after all, the idea seems simple enough. But perhaps the templates are cached somewhere else? (Or, as mentioned, I simply screwed up somewhere. I'll try it again tomorrow.)

Comment: This works fine... until you change any references, or even just update fields with no changes. Not a workable solution overall.

Comment: you rock bro.. i was searching this for hours

Answer (score 2):

In word 365, using IEEE referencing style, I couldn't change the column width, but if I clicked "distribute columns" then it let me change it until I clicked away from the table, whereupon it did not let me change it again until I distributed columns again!
At least it worked

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by choosing "fixed column width" under the autofit option and then adjusting each column width manually to fit.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is adjust the margin in your reference list. Move it to the right just a bit and everything will be okay.

Answer (score 0):

No need to change the XSL file. Click on the bibliography and the table menu appears. Open the table properties and navigate to column. There you can click on Previous Column or Next Column. I had to click on Previous Column twice to get the column where the numbers are. Now you can change the percentage of the column width. I had to choose 3%.

[image: Screenshot]

I'm using Word 2016.

Edit: Maybe you have to choose Distribute Columns before and then choose the right percentage

Comment: +1 for "choose Distribute Columns", then could drag on the table boarders

Comment: This does not survive a citations update.